# Working with adding attachment works fine on workbench but generated 404 error on site

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, attachments, pnp

While working with adding attachment to sharepoint works fine with workbench i.e.-https://sample.sharepoint.com/sites/Dev/_layouts/15/workbench.aspx

but while deployed at sharepoint site it generates 404 error like below[image]

Not sure why this is happening. here's my code. Using pnp

```
import "@pnp/sp/webs";
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp";
import "@pnp/sp/webs";
import "@pnp/sp/lists";
import "@pnp/sp/items";

private onSubmit(): void {
const endpoint: string = currentSiteUrl + `/_api/Web/lists/getbytitle('` + listName + `')/items`;
this.setState({
  status: 'Creating item...',
  items: [],
  dataNull: true
});

const body: string = JSON.stringify({
  'Title': this.state.subject,
  'Comments': this.state.comments
});

this.props.spHttpClient.post(endpoint,
  SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
  {
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
      'Content-type': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
      'odata-version': ''
    },
    body: body
  })
  .then((response: SPHttpClientResponse): Promise<IListItem> => {
    console.log(response);
    return response.json();
    console.log(response);
  })
  .then((item: IListItem): void => {
    this.setState({
      status: `created`,
      hideMessageBar: true,
      items: []
    });
  if (this.state.UploadedFilesArray !== null) {
      try {
        const web = Web(currentSiteUrl);
       let fileItem = sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listName).items.getById(item.Id);
       fileItem.attachmentFiles.add(this.state.UploadedFilesArray.name, this.state.UploadedFilesArray)
       .then((): void => {
      this.setState({
       UploadedFilesArray: null
     });
   }); 
      } catch(e){
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
    else {
      this.setState({
        comments: '',
        subject: '',
        dataNull: false,
        UploadedFilesArray: null
      });
    }
  }, (error: any): void => {
    this.setState({
      comments:'',
      subject: '',
      UploadedFilesArray: null,
      status: 'Error while creating the item: ' + error,
      items: []
    });
  });
  }
```

also after upload I want to make file empty(`UploadedFilesArray`) it has File data type, Not sure null isn't working.

I want to solve this 404 issue, not sure why this is happening.....

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting the 404 error (Not found) for either the list or the item. Be sure that the list name and item id you are specifying are correct.

A good practice is to include error handling in your function, that can give you more information on what is going wrong:

```
let fileItem = sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listName).items.getById(item.Id);
fileItem.attachmentFiles.add(this.state.UploadedFilesArray.name, this.state.UploadedFilesArray)
   .then((): void => {
    this.setState({
    UploadedFilesArray: null
  });
}).catch(error => {
  console.log(error);
});
```

**Update #2 from comments:**

Try modifying your code to look like this:

```
if (this.state.UploadedFilesArray !== null) {
    try {
        const web = Web(currentSiteUrl);
        sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listName).items.getById(item.Id)
          .attachmentFiles.add(this.state.UploadedFilesArray.name, 
            this.state.UploadedFilesArray)
                .then((): void => {
                    this.setState({UploadedFilesArray: null});
                });
    } 
    catch(e){
      console.log(e);
    }
}
```

It is possible that you will need to actually retrieve the item before doing the upload (see the `.get()` I added)

Comment: Do you have idea, to set UploadedFilesArray type empty after upload, like set state, seems like null is not working...

Comment: Do I use await? Do you suggest that? wait before creating list then perform attachment upload? Can you help me how to use await here?

Comment: I think you need to share more of your code - but with `await` you would put that in front of your statement that creates the list. It will then wait for that promise to resolve before moving on.

Comment: I am new to this, Can you help me with that?

Comment: You can edit your question and add more of your code there, it will be easier to provide you with examples then... (the code before what you already included that creates the list?)

Comment: Edited the Question with full function. You can check, Please help me to fix this issue with right approach. I am scratching  my head from past 1 week.

Comment: Updated the answer with a suggestion

Comment: Actually the previous code was working on workbench but not sure it was generating error when I deploy webpart to the site.

Comment: try just `sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listName).get().then(list => console.log(list));` to see if you are actually getting the right list.

Comment: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined`
The above code generate this error

Comment: `sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listName).get().then(list => console.log(list)); ` yes we're getting the right List with odata here

Comment: Updated last code sample again, give it a go?